# Etymology and pronunciation of arch-, archi-

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

The prefix [*arch-, archi-*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=arch-) “chief, principal; extreme, ultra; early, primitive,” derives from Latinized Greek *arkh-, arkhi-,* the combining form of *arkhos* “chief.” Usually, *arch-* is pronounced like “arch” (ɑrtʃ), and *archi-* sounds like “ark” (ɑrkɪ), although *archangel* (ɑrkeɪndʒəl) is a notable exception.

Is there an etymological or other reason for pronouncing the two prefixes differently? Did they perhaps enter English at different times? Likewise, is there any pattern to which nouns use *arch-* (e.g., *archenemy, archfiend*) versus *archi-* (*archiepiscopal, architect*)? Why is *archangel* an exception to the pronunciation rule?

Comment: OED has "/ɑːtʃ/ exc. in archangel" which it makes a complete mess of explaining.

Comment: Yes, I'd heard that the OED listed _archangel_ as a sole exception to the /ɑːtʃ/ pronunciation, but unfortunately I don't have access. I was hoping that somebody who did could offer some insight, but that doesn't sound promising.

Comment: I suspected that the difference in usage and pronunciation might be rooted in how “English” the words are, as _fiend_ is Germanic, _episcopal_ is Latinate, and _angel_ is a blend of the two. I also suspected that it might be a vowel-versus-consonant thing. Unfortunately, _archenemy_ contradicts both of those hypotheses.

Comment: Perhaps interesting: Dutch uses *aarts-* (pronounced as it is spelled) for most of those words, so *aartsbisschop, aartsengel, aartsrivaal*. Only *aarts-* is productive. But some words use the Latin/Greek spelling, like *architect*, *archetype*, *archipel*, and *architraaf*.

Comment: The OED on *archi-*: *"This form of the prefix is retained in words taken in modern times from Gr. or L., directly or through mod.Fr., and in compounds formed on the model of these. Hence it is sometimes found in the adjectives, etc. belonging to substantives, which, from their earlier introduction, have themselves the form arch-, as archdeacon, archidiaconal, archbishop, archiepiscopal. Some words have both forms, as archi-presbyter, arch-presbyter. ..."*

Comment: I suspect it's because it's transparently productive as a prefix in _archangel_; there are _angels_, and there are like General Officer _archangels_, so clearly it's a superior prefix like _Major_ or _Colonel_ in _Major General, Colonel General_. This goes along with the fact that _archangels_ are only one of the several named angel groups. And, in my schoolboy mind, at least, the _arch-_ prefix of _archangel_ got mixed up irretrievably with the _arc-_ prefix of _arcsine, arctangent, arcsecant,_ etc. That, coupled with a distaste for saying two palatal affricates in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language](https://archive.org/details/etymologicaldict00skeauoft) (1888) by Walter W. Skeat answers all your questions at once.

> **ARCH-**, chief; almost solely used as a prefix. (L.--Gk.) Shak. has 'my worthy arch and patron,' Lear, ii. I.61; but the word is harshly
>   used, and better kept as a mere prefix. In *arch-bishop*, we have a
>   word in very early use; A.S. *erce-bisceop, arce-bisceop* (Bosworth).
>   Thus *arch-* is to be rightly regarded as descended from A.S. *arce-*,
>   which was borrowed from Lat. *archi-* (in *archi-episcopus*), and this
>   again from Gk. *άρχι* in
>   *άρχιεπίσκοπος*,
>   an archbishop. Gk. *άρχός* to be first;
>   cf. Gk. *άρχή*, beginning. Cf. Skt. *arh*, to be
>   worthy; Curtius, i.233. The form of the prefix being once fixed, it
>   was used for other words. Der. *arch-bishop, arch-deacon, arch-duke,
>   arch-duchy,* &c. In the word *arch-angel*, the prefix is taken
>   directly from the Greek; see **Archi-**.
>   **ARCHI-**, chief; used as a prefix. (L.--Gk.) The older form is *arch-*, which (as explained under **Arch-**) was a modification of A.S. *arce-*, from Lat. *archi-*. **The form *archi-* is of later use,
>   but borrowed from the Lat. directly**. Gk.
>   *άρχί-*, prefix. See **Arch-**. Der. *archi-episcopal, archi-episcopy, archi-diaconal*.  **In the word *arch-angel*, the final *i* of the prefix is dropped before the vowel following**. In the word *arche-type*, the prefix takes the form
>   *arche-*.

[Another edition](http://books.google.se/books?id=jeeGAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT282&ots=rO2ZpoM_Ex) of this dictionary (revised in 1910; reprinted in 2005) adds a couple of comments to the explanation.

> **ARCH-** <...> In the word *arch-angel*, the *ch* remained hard (as *k*) in the Romance languages, on account of the *a* following; cf. Ital. *archangelo*, Span. *arcangel*.
>   **ARCHI-** <...> The same prefix also forms part of the words *archi-mandrite, archi-pelago, archi-tect, archi-trave*.

Comment: Thanks! This does a good job of explaining why _arch-_ has an English pronunciation while _archi-_ is Latinate. The explanation for _archangel_ is a little fuzzy, and I don't entirely believe either entry, but I think it's reasonable to conclude that _archangel_ was (for either etymological or aesthetic reasons) borrowed more directly from French/Latin than later words like _archenemy_ and so the more general pronunciation rule doesn't apply to it.